# Issue with If statement

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I am having an issue creating an if statement in Power Apps. What I am trying to achieve is when there is no selection from the drop down, the button stays disabled or grayed out, and then when there is a selection from the drop down, the button becomes available.

I have achieved the first part but am having issues with the second part.

I have two buttons (Daily and Monthly). If the user selects Daily, only the Daily button becomes available, and if the user selects Monthly, then the Monthly button becomes valuable.

```
If(DataCardValue22.Selected.Value=Blank() && DataCardValue22.Selected.Value="Daily", DisplayMode.Disabled, DisplayMode.Edit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set below formula in `DisplayMode` property of "Daily" button:

```
If(
    DataCardValue22.Selected.Value = "Daily",
    DisplayMode.Edit,
    DisplayMode.Disabled
)
```

And set below formula in `DisplayMode` property of "Monthly" button:

```
If(
    DataCardValue22.Selected.Value = "Monthly",
    DisplayMode.Edit,
    DisplayMode.Disabled
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
If(
     DataCardValue22.Selected.Value="" Or 
     DataCardValue22.Selected.Value="Monthly", 
     DisplayMode.Edit, 
     DisplayMode.Disabled
)
```